# PHP 7.0 extcassandra on Centos 7

Tags: centos, php, cassandra

Am I doing anything wrong when installing php with cassandra extension on a CentosOS 7 server?

For dependencies I install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm and https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm. Then I do:

```
yum install -y --enablerepo=epel,remi,remi-php70 \
php \
php-mbstring \
php-mysqlnd \
php-pecl-apcu \
php-pecl-cassandra
```

When the command finishes it always gives me:

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-cassandra-1.2.2-1.el7.remi.7.0.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libuv.so.0.10()(64bit)
```

If I try to search for libuv, the result is as follow (no 0.10 version listed):

```
yum search --enablerepo=epel,remi,remi-php70 libuv --showduplicates
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.nbtelecom.com.br
 * epel: mirror.globo.com
 * extras: centos.xpg.com.br
 * remi: remi.xpg.com.br
 * remi-php70: remi.xpg.com.br
 * remi-safe: remi.xpg.com.br
 * updates: centosp4.centos.org
============================== N/S matched: libuv ==============================
1:libuv-devel-1.9.1-1.el7.x86_64 : Development libraries for libuv
1:libuv-1.9.1-1.el7.x86_64 : Platform layer for node.js
1:libuv-static-1.9.1-1.el7.x86_64 : Platform layer for node.js - static library
php-pecl-uv-0.1.0-1.el7.remi.7.0.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-1.el7.remi.7.0.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php70-php-pecl-uv-0.1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php70-php-pecl-uv-0.1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php70-php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php70-php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php71-php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php71-php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php71-php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-2.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper
php71-php-pecl-uv-0.1.1-2.el7.remi.x86_64 : Libuv wrapper

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you found an issue (which should be better reported on [github](https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues))

libuv have been recently updated (incompatible version) in EPEL.

The new build (1.2.2-4) available in the repository fixes this issue.

```
$ rpm -qp --requires php-pecl-cassandra-1.2.2-4.el7.remi.7.0.x86_64.rpm 
libuv.so.1()(64bit)

$ rpm -qp --provides libuv-1.9.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 
libuv.so.1()(64bit)
```